# Could not extract TIF.gz file

Tags: python, gzip, 7zip, winrar

The TIF.gz file downloaded from the link below can be successfully extracted by WinRAR GUI mode manually.

ftp://ftp.glcf.umd.edu/glcf/QuickBird/02AUG15032744-X2AS_R1C1-000000185959_01_P005-Indonesia-Ujong/02AUG15032744-M2AS_R1C1-000000185959_01_P005.TIF.gz

However, it could not extract using programming mode using Python. But the similiar method below can extract other tar.gz files:

```
import subprocess
win_rar = 'C:\\Program Files\\WinRAR\\UnRAR.exe'
tif_gz_file = 'D:\\source\\02AUG15032744-M2AS_R1C1-000000185959_01_P005.TIF.gz'
subprocess.call([win_rar, 'x', tif_gz_file, 'D:\\target\\'])
```

Any idea would be highly appreciated.
I also tried the similiar procesure using 7-Zip, it also did not.
I want  to extract it using a program.
Please help me.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: the cmd prompt flash, says it could not extract file, then quits

Comment: Start a python interpreter from the windows command line (via cmd).  Type each of those commands in the interpreter and then post what error(s) you receive.

Comment: Well, what happens when you run the command you're trying to get subprocess to execute _on the command line_? How do you know the GUI mode is using the same options you are specifying?

Comment: IMPORTANT: cmd error message is "It is not RAR archive, no files to extract"

Comment: @Two-Bit Alchemist IMPORTANT: cmd error message is "It is not RAR archive, no files to extract"

Comment: See my updated answer below.  I was able to get your code to work with that change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change this:

```
win_rar = 'C:\\Program Files\\WinRAR\\UnRAR.exe'
```

to this:

```
win_rar = 'C:\\Program Files\\WinRAR\\WinRAR.exe'
```

I ran your code successfully with this change (after reproducing your error).

Comment: no success, IMPORTANT: cmd error message is "It is not RAR archive, no files to extract"